# Write SQL text inside a compilation unit

Tags: java, sql, string

I'm writing DAO objects using JdbcTemplate.

Sometimes I have long string queries with formats (tabs, new line an so on), but I don't know what is the best way to store it inside the class. Now I'm writing concatenated string, but it is not a very nice solution, for example I can not copy and paste it into a db manager... and it looks not very good:

```
public List queryTest() {
    String sql="SELECT '%c%' as Chapter,\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status IN ('new','assigned') ) AS 'New',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='document_interface' ) AS 'Document\\\r\n" + 
            " Interface',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='interface_development' ) AS 'Inter\\\r\n" + 
            "face Development',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='interface_check' ) AS 'Interface C\\\r\n" + 
            "heck',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='document_routine' ) AS 'Document R\\\r\n" + 
            "outine',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='full_development' ) AS 'Full Devel\\\r\n" + 
            "opment',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='peer_review_1' ) AS 'Peer Review O\\\r\n" + 
            "ne',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%'AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='peer_review_2' ) AS 'Peer Review Tw\\\r\n" + 
            "o',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='qa' ) AS 'QA',\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT count(ticket.id) AS Matches FROM engine.ticket INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%'AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine' AND ticket.status='closed' ) AS 'Closed',\r\n" + 
            "count(id) AS Total,\r\n" + 
            "ticket.id AS _id\r\n" + 
            "FROM engine.ticket\r\n" + 
            "INNER JOIN engine.ticket_custom ON ticket.id = ticket_custom.ticket\r\n" + 
            "WHERE ticket_custom.name='chapter' AND ticket_custom.value LIKE '%c%' AND type='New material' AND milestone='1.1.12' AND component NOT LIKE 'internal_engine'";
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,rmapper);
}
```

How can I store sql text inside a class?

Comment: What about putting them in a property file?

Comment: Read the SQL from a file.

Comment: Why don't you store it elsewhere, like an XML file, and just read it from there?

Comment: and why have the `\r\n`?

Comment: property file is a plain text file... I really don't want that someone change it directly from filesystem. I know that somecone can decompile it, but it is a bit more difficut than change a property file.

Comment: \r\n is used for debugging purposes (example what I need to export the SQL string to a file or a debug log)

Answer (score 0):

Like said in comments, you should store in a properties XML file.

The advantages of XML overs plain properties files is that you can use CDATA blocks to get multi-line queries correctly.

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties version="1.0">
  <entry key="query"><![CDATA[
...
]]></entry>
</properties>
```

And then, in your code :

```
try (InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("queries.xml")) {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.loadFromXML(is);
  this.query = Objects.requireNonNull(properties.get("query"), "queries.xml#query");
}
```

However, if you use Spring JDBC Template, you should probably use Spring facilities (either by setting the query via XML, either by loading the properties files as a resource).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to CREATE VIEW on database and use a simple sql query to get the data from the VIEW

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MyBatis](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/) framework.

It is a wrapper over JDBC which provides nice SQL template engine. It typically stores SQL templates in XML files. Good alternative to Spring JdbcTemplete. Also it is supported well by IDEs. I've replaced Spring JdbcTemplate with MyBatis in several projects.

Comment: I know it, but I don't want to add another framework, I'm exiting from the hibernate nightmare, I really prefer a simple xml instead of another framwork.

Comment: Not add but replace. Spring template is also a framework. There is no magic in MyBatis. You still write plain SQL.